# Configure prettier to recognise Admonition markdown

Tags: markdown, prettier, mkdocs

We are using [Prettier for VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) to keep our markdown tidy. In our markdown for [MKDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/) we use the [admonition extension](https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/admonitions/). It produced nice boxes using a simple syntax:

```markdown
!!! note "Some title"
    This is the note text
    inside the box
```

Unfortunately prettier doesn't like the 4 leading spaces and removes them. Removing leading spaces is OK for other parts of the document. Our [current solution](https://prettier.io/docs/en/ignore.html) is a little cumbersome:

```markdown
<!-- prettier-ignore -->
!!! note "Some title"
    This is the note text
    inside the box
```

Is there a way to configure Prettier to recognise the admonition syntax and leave the spaces in place, so we don't need to decorate each admonition using `<!-- prettier-ignore -->`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using [prettier pre-commit hook](https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-prettier) but hopefully it also works for VSCode extension.

You should add a blank line between the title and the body of the notes

```
!!! note "Some title"

    This is the note text
    inside the box
```

It gives the following output:

[image]

---

Here is my configuration of prettier:

```yaml
  - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-prettier
    rev: v2.2.1
    hooks:
      - id: prettier
        args:
          - --print-width=100
          - --prose-wrap=always
          - --tab-width=2
```

Here is my configuration for `mkdocs`:

- packages

```
mdx-truly-sane-lists==1.3
mkdocs==1.3.0
mkdocs-git-revision-date-plugin==0.3.2
mkdocs-material==8.2.11
mkdocs-material-extensions==1.0.3
pymdown-extensions==9.1
```

- extensions in `mkdoc.yml`

```yaml
markdown_extensions:
  # support emojis
  - pymdownx.emoji:
      emoji_index: !!python/name:materialx.emoji.twemoji
      emoji_generator: !!python/name:materialx.emoji.to_svg
  # both following extensions add lines into code blocks
  - pymdownx.highlight:
      linenums: true
  - pymdownx.superfences
  # support pad width = 2, as formatted with prettier
  - mdx_truly_sane_lists
  # Allow to use collapsible call-outs
  # https://squidfunk.github.io/mkdocs-material/reference/admonitions/
  - admonition
  - pymdownx.details
```